# Unity animation from foreach loop c#

Tags: c#, foreach, unity-game-engine

I have a UI text that I update in script off camera then uses an animation to have it slide across the screen. The script uses a foreach loop since the text change and number of times the animation runs are variable. It always skips the third animation (it will print the effect in console but will not play that animation), even when 4 or 5 effects are called.

```cs
private Animation Anim;
public Text NBtext;
public GameObject NBEffect, Tut, TouchInput;

public IEnumerator NiceBowlingEffects(List<string> Effects, bool FirstFrame)
{
    Anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
    NBEffect.SetActive(true);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.2f); //give frame ect a chance to load.
    foreach (var Effect in Effects)
    {
        NBtext.text = Effect;
        Print(Effect);
        Anim.Play();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Anim.clip.length);
    }
    NBEffect.SetActive(false);
    if (FirstFrame)
    {
        Tut.SetActive(true);
    }
    TouchInput.SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: Can you show a video of it? Would like to see it.

Comment: Sure Might take me a min

Comment: The video is uploading should be available at https://youtu.be/NtnyoUQhUsQ in ~ 2 hours... Sorry I have a slow connection. The first 2 frames the third effect's animation is not played.

Comment: If you play the animation in the `List` one by one with the index, do they all work? For example, `Effects[0].Play()`...`Effects[1].Play()` ......

Comment: Its the same animation each time, the Effects list is just a list of strings that I'm using to update the text before the animation starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing "**WaitForSeconds**" to "**WaitForSecondsRealtime**" in the foreach loop, and tell me if it fixed it

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but it did not change anything. I'm going to edit my question with some new information I figured out while trying to capture this error on video. basically it is only skipping the third animation, if it has 4 animations it still skips the 3rd then plays the 4th like normal..

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps someone but to finally get this to work for Nice Bowling I had to add a time delay between changing the text and playing the animation. Here's the code that's running on Nice Bowling right now.

```
public IEnumerator NiceBowlingEffects(List<string> Effects, bool FirstFrame)
{
    Anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
    NBEffect.SetActive(true);
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(.1f); //give frame ect a chance to load.
    foreach (var Effect in Effects)
    {
        NBtext.text = Effect;
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(.1f); //text time to change
        Anim.Play();
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(Anim.clip.length +.01f);
    }
    NBEffect.SetActive(false);
    if (FirstFrame)
    {
        Tut.SetActive(true);
        Tut.GetComponent<UISprite>().Trigger();
    }
    TouchInput.SetActive(true);
}
```